# Can I switch 44 teeth Chainring to 50 teeth

Tags: shimano, chainring

System: Shimano Claris 2000, 1x8 speed.

Comment: Yes! But you'll probably also need a new chain.

Comment: @JoeK please post answers an answers. The comment field tells to not answer in comments for a reason.

Comment: Why do you want to use a larger chainring?  There might be better and easier ways to get what you want, such as simply changing your cassette.  Your bike may not provide enough clearance or an appropriate front derailleur mount location for a 50-tooth chainring.

Comment: I want to go faster

Comment: Bigger gears don't make you faster.  A better engine - you - does.  Pedaling at 100 RPM with a 44-tooth chainring and the chain on the 11-tooth cog gets you over 31 mph or about 50 kph.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is maybe. Mostly depending on if you will have enough clearance on your chainstay. According to [this chart](https://www.wolftoothcomponents.com/pages/chainring-diameter-by-tooth-count), a 44 tooth chainring would have a diameter of 184.6mm, while a 50 tooth chainring would have a diameter of 208.8mm, that's an extra 12.1 mm (24.2mm ÷ 2), or just under a half inch of clearance over what you would have already.

If you don't have enough clearance, you could get a bottom bracket with a slightly longer axle. Although you shouldn't push it too far as you will have problems with the chainline if your bottom bracket axle is too long.

See the image below to see how a larger chainstay could have problems with chainstay clearance. Also, as mentioned in the comments, you will need a longer chain.

According to [this answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/56337/ideal-distance-between-chainring-and-chain-stay). You should keep about 4mm as minimum clearance between the chainstay and the chainring.

[image: chainstay clearance]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.