# Is the Neco B910 bottom bracket's square taper JIS or ISO?

Tags: crankset, bottom-bracket

I'm looking to replace my cup and cone bottom bracket as my current one has deep grooves on  the spindle. Because for some reason replacement spindles (113 total width, 68 shell width)  are very difficult to find (please comment if that's the case in general - I could find only 2 auctions for a 113/68 spindle on some shady websites), I've decided to look for a cartridge bearing bottom bracket.

The only Italian threaded, square taper ("cottorless"), closest to 113mm - 113.5/68 - bottom bracket I could find in Poland is the Neco B910. The problem is that none of the auctions, nor the manufacturer's website mention whether the square taper is ISO or JIS.

[The manufacturer's website says the spindle is 10B21](https://www.necoparts.com/en/product/Cartridge-Cotterless-B.B.-Sets/B910%2C+B910E%2C+B910P%2C+B910B%2C+B910PP.html) but that seems like an internal codename, so no luck here either.

Comment: I understand this question and answer could evoke some "huh so now you're gonna do a question like that for every part and say to check the catalog?" feeling but this particular manufacturer seems pretty oblivious to ISO/JIS and doesn't report it at all, so this answer could be useful in general

Comment: Manufacturers these days are pretty oblivious to ISO/JIS because the last mainstream brand stopped making ISO cranks 20 years ago. And no, the thought evoked is not "now you're gonna do a question" but "now you're gonna spam copypaste from every catalogue".

Answer (score 2):

It's JIS.

If you look closely in [the catalogue](https://www.necoparts.com/Templates/att/2020-2021CATALOGUE-BOTTOM%20BRACKETS.pdf?lng=en), you'll see that the cross-sections contain the spindle measurements:
[image]

And if we refer to [an answer from the bicycle stack exchange](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/37756/65434), we can tell it's JIS because JIS has a width of 12.65mm and the manufacturer in the picture above says the square taper has a width of 12.65mm aswell.